# Combinations of n elements choosing r elements without repetition (Objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, combinations

I have an array of objects (n).
I want to output an array of unique objects by selecting (r) elements at a time.

For example: 
n = 600,
r = 10

How can we get an array of all possible unique solutions?

I realize that this is the binomial coefficient formula (and also that the solution set is enormous), but I'm having trouble figuring out a way to implement it that won't exceed memory constraints.

Something that may help the implementation details (from a memory concern) is that for every possible combination, I can apply certain rules to it to confirm if its of any relevance to me or not (in a lot of cases the combination will be of no use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple algorithm that will let you produce all the r-combinations of the integers from 0 to n-1 if you call it enough times. What the algorithm does is take an r-vector representing a combination, and advance it in-place to the next combination (in lexicographical order). You could use such a vector to index a vector of objects.

Given a vector `v0...vr-1`:

- Find the largest `j < r` such that `vj < n - r + j`
- Increment element `j`.
- For each `k` such that `j < k` and `k < r`, set `vk` to `vj + k - j`

Here's a simple and reasonably efficient C solution (although not everyone will appreciate the style). The function returns `false` if the current combination is the last one. The vector should be initialized to the sequence `0...r-1`, in order to iterate over the entire set of possibilities.

```
bool next_combination(int *comb, int n, int r) {
  for (int j = r - 1, v = n - 1; j >= 0; --j, --v) {
    if (comb[j] < v) {
      for (v = comb[j] + 1; j < r; ++j, ++v)
        comb[j] = v;
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

However, I really don't think generating all the possible <sub>600</sub>C<sub>10</sub> values is going to be practical, even if you don't try to store them all in an array. <sub>600</sub>C<sub>10</sub> is 1,545,269,050,621,668,869,640. If you could process 10<sup>9</sup> combinations in a second (i.e., one every nanosecond), it would still take you about 48,965 years to get through the entire list.

So you might want to think about how to generate only the combinations you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks @rici, this is exactly what I was looking for. And yeah, I agree, I need to find a way generate only the combos that I'm interested in, or at the very least reduce the input size.